# Vue - Is it possible to use Vuex getters in the computed property of a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In my vuex-store has different variables, for example `loggedIn`. Now I need to use this variable from the `computed` section of my component, because I want to filter the array based on the variable value.

Here you can see how I want to use it in my code

```
<td v-for="(item, index) in navLinks" :item="navLink" :key="index">
  <router-link :to="{ name: item.name }" class="router-links" exact>{{ item.text }}</router-link>
</td>
```

And this is the relevant part of my `script` section:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['user', 'loggedIn']),
  navLinks: [
    {
      vif: !this.loggedIn,
      name: 'Register',
      text: 'Registrieren',
    },
    {
      vif: this.loggedIn,
      name: 'Logout',
      text: 'Logout',
    },
  ],
},
```

I always get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of undefined

So I think that I can't use Vuex getters before a component mounts because `this` is not defined..?

If I used `navLinks` in the `data` with `v-if`-directives, I'd get an error because v-if bindings are not allowed with v-for bindings.

So how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navLinks` should be a function that returns an array :

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['user', 'loggedIn']),
  navLinks(){
  return [
    {
      vif: !this.loggedIn,
      name: 'Register',
      text: 'Registrieren',
    },
    {
      vif: this.loggedIn,
      name: 'Logout',
      text: 'Logout',
    },
  ];
 ),
},
```

Comment: You're right: In computed, there should be functions, not variables... Thank you!